# 301 redirect from query string to simple URL

Tags: linux, http-status-code-301

I've had a good look through the first ten pages of search results for "301 redirects" and can't find the answer so here goes...

I've moved from a crappy old CMS that didn't give my pages nice URLs to one that does and I want to set up a 301 redirect for my key pages.

Current URL:  http://www.domain.com/?pid=22
New URL:      http://www.domain.com/contact/

I'm using Wordpress and my current htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. All you need to do is check to see if you are on page X and then redirect to page Y. Consider RewriteCond statements to be 'if' statements. If you need more redirects just duplicate the last two lines and edit the paths.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com\/?pid=22$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/contact [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the query string for the value in the "pid" variable and then redirect if the value in that variable matches a page you want to redirect.  You can do this with the "RewriteCond" and "RewriteRule" directives like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect pid=22 to http://www.domain.com/contact
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=22$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/contact [R=301,L]
```

You can repeat the "RewriteCond" and "RewriteRule" directives to create additional redirects.